# Properties of dynamical systems in general

Tags: dynamical-systems

## Question

A [normed vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_vector_space) or is a vector space over the real or complex numbers, on which a norm is defined.

While this definition does not mentions any metric, we know that the norm will induce a metric on the underlying set of the normed vector space.
The additional metric is, so to speak, a property of a normed vector space, which can be infered from the definition without being part of the definition.

I am interested in such properties for dynamical systems that exist for every dynamical system without being part of the definition. What else can be said about dynamical systems in general?

## Dynamical System Definition

One [definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/475468/340174) defines a dynamical system like this (I shortened it slightly):

> You've got a set, and the points in it are moving around with the passage of time, and $\Phi$ is keeping track of the movement. $T$ as giving the time. $\Phi(0,x)=x$ says that at time zero the points are at their starting places. The third condition says that if you look at where the points are after $t_1$ seconds (or days, or centuries, whatever), and then you look at where they are $t_2$ seconds later, you find out where they are after $t_1+t_2$ seconds.

In my publication I am considering the [general definition from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamical_system_(definition)), where $T$ is not related to time in the physical sense:

> A dynamical system is a tuple $(T, M, Φ)$ where $T$ is a monoid, written additively, $M$ is a non-empty set and $Φ$ is a function
>
> $$\Phi :U\subseteq (T\times M)\to M$$
>
> with
>
> - $\mathrm {proj} _{2}(U)=M$ (where $\mathrm {proj} _{2}$ is the 2nd projection map)
> - $I(x)=\{t\in T:(t,x)\in U\}$
> - $\Phi (0,x)=x$
> - $\Phi (t_{2},\Phi (t_{1},x))=\Phi (t_{2}+t_{1}, x)$ for $t_{1},\,t_{2}+t_{1}\in I(x)$ and $t_{2}\in I(\Phi (t_{1},x))$
>
> The function $Φ(t,x)$ is called the evolution function of the
> dynamical system: it associates to every point in the set $M$ a unique
> image, depending on the variable $t$, called the evolution parameter.
> M is called phase space or state space, while the variable $x$
> represents an initial state of the system.

## Example: Local search

While I am interested in the general question above, here is an example from my research. There I am studying [local search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_search_(optimization)), which I define like this:

> Given a target function $f(x), x\in X$,  over a topological space $(X, \tau)$ and an objective regarding the target function (e.g. minimization), then local search optimization is defined as the family of functions $L = (l_t)_{t\in\mathcal T}$ with $t,T \in \mathbb N\cup\{ \infty \}, \mathcal T = \{t \mid 1 \le t \le T\}$, such that $x_{t+1}=l_t(x_t) \in N_t(x_t)$ induces a sequence $\{x_t\}_{t=1}^T$ (with $x_t \in X$) for neighborhood $N_t(x)$ over $X$ such that $f(x_{t+1})$ is closer to the objective than $f(x_t)$ (e.g. f(x_{t+1}) < f(x_t) in the case of minimization). The tuple $( \mathcal T ,X,L)$ is a semi-cascading discrete-time dynamical system.

## Background (Why the interest?)

For my publication I defined $T, M, Φ$. Put together, they obviously make up a dynamical system.
However, even though $T, M, Φ$ interlace, I just them, not defintion-independent properties of the dynamical system, the triplet ($T, M, Φ$).
So, my supervisor said - because I am not using the dynamical system's properties - I should not mention in my publication that they make up a dynamical system.
He said, it will make the read more difficult, since a reader might ask themselves, what the dynamical system (as a whole) is used for and whether they need to learn about dynamical systems if they want to understand the paper.
I think he has a point and realized I do not know what - if any - properties dynamical systems have in general - except for the properties from the definition above.

---

This is not a dublicate to [Properties of a dynamical system](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2238203/properties-of-a-dynamical-system), because the other question is asking for a specific dynamical system.